# How to refresh uib-datepicker element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm loading data dynamically for each month, once it is opened in calendar. I have set the inline options, and provided custom class that return state for each date. And now I need some kind of a refresh on the uib-datepicker once when all data is loaded.

Comment: Please post your code. Add plnke/jsfidle if possible.

Comment: Will do that once will be back home, could take few days :(